# Thermal Conductivity - value meaning

Tags: thermodynamics

What does the thermal conductivity value mean for a certain material? For example:
wool (watts, meter, kelvin):

$k = 0.04\,\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-1}\,\mathrm{K}^{-1}$

What does this mean?
If I give the material 0.04 watts, the temperature increases by 1 kelvin?

Comment: I agree with your approach to try to interpret the material property using its units. Here, though you have an extra meter in the units with no corresponding interpretation. In fact, the *heat capacity* (which is different from the thermal conductivity, which is described by @Sebastian below) has units of J/K, which is compatible with your interpretation of "give the material X joules of energy, get a temperature increase of 1 kelvin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thermal conductivity has nothing to do with increasing the temperature by applying mechanical work.

Take a slab of the material of thickness $l$ and an area of $A$ if the temperature difference between the two sides of the slab is $\Delta T$, then the heat flowing through the slab in a time interval $\Delta t$ in the steady state will be:
$$Q = k \frac{A \Delta T} l \Delta t.$$
That is the thermal conductivity gives the power (in the sense energy per time) of the heat flow through the material in dependence of the temperature difference in a way that is independent of the geometry of the object but only depends on the material.

The same idea is behind the definition of the resistivity $\rho$ of a material. We get the resistance of a prismatic component by:
$$R = \rho l / A.$$
Again, given the geometry of the object we can derive its properties using the material constant.